# Rest API call return 0 items in list even there's data when using App deamon model

Tags: rest, oauth

In a list I have some items. I want to call Rest api to list these items.

When I call the api url from the browser, I get the expected result (items are returned).

When I call the api from Insomnia Rest client, I get no result. By no result I mean the result set is returned without error, but empty.

What I've done :

- in AAD portal, I registered a new application, a client ID and an App Secret.
- I autorize (admin consent) :

  - Microsoft Graph : `Sites.Read.All` and `Sites.ReadWrite.All`
  - SharePoint : `Sites.FullControl.All`, `Sites.Manage.All`, `Sites.Read.All` and `Sites.ReadWrite.All`
- in insomnia, I set up OAuth 2.0 authentication :

  - Grant type : Authorization Code
  - Authorization Url : `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://mytenant.sharepoint.com`
  - Access token Url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token`
  - Client ID: `my generated client ID`
  - Client secret : `my generated secret`
  - Redirect URL : `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient`
  - Header : only `Accept`=`application/json;odata=verbose` because authentication headers are handled by insomnia.

The url I target is `https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitecoll/_api/Web/Lists(guid'b6e9527d-a902-4b15-b77b-d49e701fdd92')/items`.

The result of this call is (status `200 OK`):

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": []
  }
}
```

As you can see there's no error, but no data.

What's puzzling me is that calling : `https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitecoll/_api/Web/Lists(guid%27b6e9527d-a902-4b15-b77b-d49e701fdd92%27)?%24select=ItemCount` actually returns :

```
{
  "d": {
    "__metadata": {
      ....
    },
    "ItemCount": 3
  }
}
```

There is data.

What's missing ?

As a side note, using the Graph, everything is ok :  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mytenant.sharepoint.com,b969074a-6a95-4235-a520-17893eca8fbe,4d32dad1-6bcc-4b57-becc-7e476c851046/lists/b6e9527d-a902-4b15-b77b-d49e701fdd92/items returns expected data

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with permissions..

For test just try to add permissions to specific list/library

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">  
  <AppPermissionRequest
    Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" 
    Right="FullControl"
  />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

And choose list/library in a step after you press create..

Comment: Thanks for you help, but this ACS permission, not AAD permission

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Later I found I made a mistake on the below Scope attribute value. I was putting my List URL below but it is actually a static text

```
Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list"
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but this ACS permission, not AAD permission